# Calculate non linear regression (nls()) prediction interval without a library

Tags: prediction-interval, nls

I wouldlike to know how to calculate a prediction interval manually, without using a library. Ultimate goal is to write some formula in a spreadsheet based on the model params that would let me calculate a prediction interval around a table of new values.

Some data to illustrate (R):

```
library(tidyverse)
example_data <- 
    structure(list(cohort_id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L), levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12"), class = "factor"), billing_cycle = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), sample_survival_rate = c(0.632200401198071, 
0.471913267003986, 0.378296178210082, 0.319076805051261, 0.292029618036517, 
0.274045639213876, 0.264550532374741, 0.25802116016373, 0.254557833462643, 
0.252436623787252, 0.25149346632024, 0.251071225964245, 0.620653483104977, 
0.461030916824388, 0.380163176348694, 0.321488395966094, 0.29026744669537, 
0.27523738814867, 0.262925145451852, 0.258026173985553, 0.255009657605463, 
0.252797811547626, 0.252544245569946, 0.249975487155656, 0.630862518862165, 
0.47133115349959, 0.382989313181497, 0.32248066541694, 0.289734136346638, 
0.276359005316901, 0.263254193357564, 0.258049123703156, 0.254549688843134, 
0.252265731552128, 0.252362026829707, 0.250006800717875, 0.624053386400491, 
0.469930134235929, 0.374609857775017, 0.32688577834419, 0.289504109848162, 
0.276470387361543, 0.262372498330842, 0.257880919304361, 0.255376480438952, 
0.253489296380972, 0.251009351196471, 0.252151054708995, 0.633309736432007, 
0.477915634902749, 0.372915904844898, 0.3251374304375, 0.28982919518413, 
0.271834445646529, 0.263792745147088, 0.258036863714587, 0.254360580071268, 
0.252197885869253, 0.251479462547415, 0.251431663370279, 0.619990670000958, 
0.455382851415977, 0.371527031579931, 0.314170306429677, 0.287324180674886, 
0.274448010216251, 0.263866725628501, 0.258020648909941, 0.254335327084417, 
0.252626113186729, 0.252481641175136, 0.251174203083612, 0.628108972989331, 
0.461477825607533, 0.36992048306531, 0.318306475361083, 0.289523080094554, 
0.273263444502067, 0.263713449269264, 0.257978223987167, 0.254856004127562, 
0.252093238775155, 0.251304190468171, 0.250866134714494, 0.627111084929375, 
0.466994977668696, 0.391612132457849, 0.330612688512934, 0.289888548913264, 
0.275770032622184, 0.264032307828391, 0.257972859837413, 0.254369374783836, 
0.253380317293905, 0.251322025972975, 0.250365512396057, 0.631666315344183, 
0.464755138198706, 0.38086071235036, 0.323417703404163, 0.296178210639493, 
0.273130076650956, 0.262512741029117, 0.257800410374838, 0.254565303897926, 
0.252327173683508, 0.251486889918762, 0.250724533720317, 0.632042608013315, 
0.471887771877749, 0.381384759240115, 0.325179239212888, 0.293132357350765, 
0.273136362713514, 0.263209219441725, 0.258003519322355, 0.254708003410392, 
0.253158926905167, 0.251477450959353, 0.2500632480691, 0.624662420853751, 
0.459518318406197, 0.373432281223013, 0.324941888208225, 0.290906386970158, 
0.272800157806119, 0.263477702996681, 0.258064622807424, 0.254759772915721, 
0.252023884074646, 0.251286897866664, 0.251926361083808, 0.621710131621103, 
0.469358762221455, 0.368498951236529, 0.332141890383277, 0.288766556691676, 
0.272096957712154, 0.263609660466783, 0.257985273715483, 0.254910602359154, 
0.251740628824699, 0.25213250992765, 0.250798671898234)), row.names = c(NA, 
-144L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The above block creates a data frame example_data. Here's a plot of the fields of interest:

```
survival_plot <- example_data |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = billing_cycle, y = sample_survival_rate, color = cohort_id)) +
  geom_line()
survival_plot
```

[image]

Then I fit a model:

```
exponential_decay <- function(i, a, lambda, billing_cycle) i + a * exp(-lambda * billing_cycle)
mod.nls <- nls(sample_survival_rate ~ 
                 exponential_decay(i, a, lambda, billing_cycle), data = example_data, start = list(i = 0.5, a = 0.5, lambda = 0.15))

mod.nls %>% summary()

Formula: sample_survival_rate ~ exponential_decay(i, a, lambda, billing_cycle)

Parameters:
        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
i      0.2498026  0.0004586   544.7   <2e-16 ***
a      0.6522447  0.0029281   222.8   <2e-16 ***
lambda 0.5477209  0.0032837   166.8   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.003436 on 141 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 6 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 6.495e-08
```

I can make a prediction on new data e.g:

```
nd <- data.frame(billing_cycle = 1:5)
> predict(mod.nls, newdata = nd)
[1] 0.6269737 0.4679079 0.3759255 0.3227352 0.2919771
```

How can I calculate a 95% prediction interval around these predictions using formula/manual calculations?

Comment: You don't.  Merely fitting this nonlinear model requires so much computation that (a) it would take months of manual calculation just to carry it out and (b) there's no closed-form formula for doing it: as the output states, it requires *iteration.*  What you *can* do is post-process some of the auxiliary results optionally output by `nls` -- but you won't do that with a spreadsheet!

Comment: Thanks for the information here @whuber! OK. I don't understand this sentence: " What you can do is post-process some of the auxiliary results optionally output by nls"

Comment: See, for instance, the help pages (and code) for `profile.nls` and `predict.nls`.