# Can I adjust lambda by 1 or 2 S.E. in exponential decay to potential improvements in retention

Tags: survival, exponential-family, nls

(Similar example data to a post I made [posted yesterday](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/621640/calculate-non-linear-regression-nls-prediction-interval-without-a-library?noredirect=1#comment1156910_621640) but a completely different question)

I have an exponential decay with off-set function that looks like this:

```
exponential_decay <- function(i, a, lambda, billing_cycle) i + a * exp(-lambda * billing_cycle)
```

I'm interested in showing some realistic scenarios of this decay curve fluctuating around.

My example data look like this (I can share example data but I don't think it's needed for this post):

```
survival_plot <- example_data |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = billing_cycle, y = sample_survival_rate, color = cohort_id)) +
  geom_line()
survival_plot
```

[image]

After fitting a model using R's non linear regression `nls()` I get the following model:

```
mod.nls <- nls(sample_survival_rate ~ 
                 exponential_decay(i, a, lambda, billing_cycle), data = example_data, start = list(i = 0.5, a = 0.5, lambda = 0.15))

mod.nls %>% summary()

Formula: sample_survival_rate ~ exponential_decay(i, a, lambda, billing_cycle)

Parameters:
        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
i      0.2498026  0.0004586   544.7   <2e-16 ***
a      0.6522447  0.0029281   222.8   <2e-16 ***
lambda 0.5477209  0.0032837   166.8   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.003436 on 141 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 6 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 6.495e-08
```

Here's a [desmos of this modeled decay line](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qoe7y1ifsj). I show the modeled decay curve in red and a blue line showing what lambda would be if it was 0. If lambda was zero, retention would be 100%, so the closer to zero lambda is the better.

Suppose my real nls model has a larger standard error of `0.032837` and I added a new line with lambda smaller by 2 standard errors:  `0.5477209 - (2 * 0.032837) = 0.4820469`

Desmos looks like this now ([see link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qoe7y1ifsj)):
[image]

The smaller lambda shows a slight improvement in retention.

Is my approach to modeling what a potential improvement in lambda might look like sound? i.e. adjusting lambda by 1 or 2 standard errors?